# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo changing folder permissions

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an application that creates a database using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo. The database gets created in a directory alongside the debug folder. Unfortunately, by creating the database there, folder permissions on the folder it's created and the directory above it are changed in a way that breaks the program.

Is there a way to change this behavior within the Database object or is this a SQL property that needs to be changed?

I'm running sql server 2008 r2.

Comment: what error do you get? What does break the program mean?

Comment: AFAIK SMO `Database.Create` does not change any folder permissions.